# How can I return row for cell if the cell data matches another cell from a different CSV file? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare perceptual hash values that are stored in CSV files: a CSV for each type of modification performed on the image and a CSV for the originals.
How can I extract the hash values from the CSV file when the filename from the Original matches the filename from the modified images CSV?

It is my goal for each hash value for each image in the Original CSV dataset, compare each hash value from each of the other CSV files when and only when the filenames match. So far, I have the filenames matching, but I want to access the data stored in the other columns.

```
    originalImages_path = 'FullPath\\Python Project\\Images\\Original'
    path = 'FullPath\\Python Project\\Images\\'
    fields = ['Filename', 'aHash', 'pHash', 'wHash', 'DHash', 'ColorHash']
    originalImages_CSV = pd.read_csv(originalImages_path + '\\Originalimagehashes.csv', usecols=fields)


    for AHash_Original in originalImages_CSV.Filename:
        AHash_OriginalStrip = AHash_Original.replace('Original', '').split('.')

        for folder in os.listdir(path):
            if folder != 'Original':
            
                for file in os.listdir(path + folder):
                
                    if file.endswith('.csv'):
                        modifiedImagesCSV = pd.read_csv(path + folder + '\\' + file, usecols=fields)
                    
                        for modifiedImage in modifiedImagesCSV.Filename:
                            modifiedImageName = modifiedImage.split('_')

                            if AHash_OriginalStrip[0] == modifiedImageName[0]:
                                print(f'MATCH! {AHash_Original} and {modifiedImage}')
```

The above code shows me that I can successfully match each original image to its modified version in each of the modified CSVs. I am unsure where to go from here and have been struggling with the logic behind it. The code above is just for aHash, however there are 4 other hash algorithms I have stored and would like to compare. The final goal is to get the values of the hashes and pass them into a function that calculates hamming distance.

(CSV File of one of the modified image hashes [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUnAH.png

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't really understand

Comment: I am trying to calculate hamming distance between the original image hash and the hash of its modified version. So I need the hash values extracted from the CSV file and passed through a function. I tried to upload some screenshots to help clarify but I was unable to.

Comment: Could you upload the CSV? There probably is a python module to pull variables out of CSV files

Comment: uploaded a screenshot, will that suffice?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, so you want to check the Ahash of lets say the first one and compare it to the others right?

Comment: Hey no problem. What I want to do is compare all the hashes of, for example 0_FlipX.jpg with the hashes of the same file I have in another CSV file. So the screenshot is a CSV file containing the perceptual hashes of the Original images but have been flipped on the X axis. I want to compare each type of hash with the corresponding hash with hashes for the Original images. So like..."for each (aHash,pHash,DHash etc). if filename is same as filename in Original CSV, compare aHash, pHash, DHash etc.).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the way to do it would be to have the coordinates for the first cell (0,1) and just go through it systematically, incrementing the x value and comparing the cell in the first file to the second. Once it reaches the end set x to zero and increment y.

If the csv files look different you could also add tests for the amount of cols and rows